# How to set/write list item values in a CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am writing a script to produce unique asset numbers for parts we have at work. There is a preference on how these asset numbers are created. If, for example, we have a part number and a serial number on record (i.e. the cells are not blank), the unique asset number should be a joining of the two. In the CSV file this would be:

> column[9] + '-' + column[12]

The last preference for how asset numbers are created is a completely made up but unique number, which I have used the list() function to create.

I have been able to open and read the CSV file the data comes from, however I don't know how to write/edit the asset numbers into the file. The asset numbers are column[16] for each line in the CSV. I am used to working in C and expected if I set column[16] to a certain value, it would change column[16] to that value in the file I was working with.

```
import csv

list1 = list(range(500))
for item in list1:
    list1[item] = "RAND" + "-" + str(item).zfill(6)

with open('data.csv', mode='r') as csv:
    for num, line in enumerate(csv):
        column = line.strip().split(',')
        if column[9] != '' and column[12] != '':
            column[16] = column[9] + '-' + column[12]
        elif column[8] != '' and column[12] != '':
            column[16] = column[8] + '-' + column[12]
        elif column[10] != '' and column[12] != '':
            column[16] = column[10] + '-' + column[12]        
        elif column[12] != '':
            column[16] = column[12]
        elif:
            column[16] = list1[num]
```

Sample data:

```
PLCN,MLCN,PLCN Description,PLCN Unique ID,Remarks,Location,Classification,Part Number,Part Description,LSA Number,Serial Number,SN Description,Barcode Number,OMEGAPS LocationParent,Parent,MLCN Parent,Asset
H 1111,1111,Example Part,,,Brisbane,None,,PART100,LSA100,SERIAL100,,BAR100,,H 111,111,
H 1111,1111,Example Part,,,Brisbane,None,,PART100,,SERIAL100,,BAR100,,H 111,111,
H 1111,1111,Example Part,,,Brisbane,None,,,,SERIAL100,,BAR100,,H 111,111,
H 1111,1111,Example Part,,,Brisbane,None,,,,,,BAR100,,H 111,111,
H 1111,1111,Example Part,,,Brisbane,None,,,,,,,,H 111,111,
```

Comment: No problem, have listed some now.

Comment: Yes they exist. They are blank cells that have been exported to CSV

Comment: I see `partnumber` have Null data

Comment: Yes some cells are blank on some lines. I have set it up like that on purpose as test cases. The code should first check for LSA Number and Barcode Number, then failing that, Part Number and Barcode number etc. I just want to know how to write column[16] into the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Part Number` and `Serial Number` is not None. You can use pandas to achieve this easily.

```
df = pd.read_csv("dummy.csv")
df["Unique_Id"] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x["Part Number"])+'_'+str(x["Serial Number"]), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Yes I understand there is an easier way to do the logic for it, but I simply want to know how to write column[16] into the CSV at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I have worked it out. Just needed to create a list, append all the results of the first for loop to that list and write it out to the same file:

```
import csv

list1 = list(range(500))
for item in list1:
    list1[item] = "RAND" + "-" + str(item).zfill(6)

list2 = []

with open('test.csv', mode='r') as csv:
    for num, line in enumerate(csv):
        column = line.strip().split(',')
        if column[9] != '' and column[12] != '':
            column[16] = column[9] + '-' + column[12]
        elif column[8] != '' and column[12] != '':
            column[16] = column[8] + '-' + column[12]
        elif column[10] != '' and column[12] != '':
            column[16] = column[10] + '-' + column[12]        
        elif column[12] != '':
            column[16] = column[12]
        else:
            column[16] = list1[num]
        list2.append(','.join(column))

with open('data.csv', mode='w') as new:
    for line in list2:
        new.write(line + '\n')
        print (line)
```